OR condition on value of XML nodes
I need to check the value of XML node.
But why is this not working?
 <xsl:if test="(applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode != 'ABC' or 
 applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode != 'XYZ')">

I have tried this too
 <xsl:if test="(applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode != 'ABC') or 
 (applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode != 'XYZ')">

and this
 <xsl:if test="applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode != 'ABC' or 
 applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode != 'XYZ'">

please help!

Please show us minimal but complete samples of both the XML input data and the XSLT code to allow us to reproduce the problem. And of course explain what "is not working", i.e. which result you expect and which one you get. And it also helps to explain in plain English what you want to check, whether you want to check that there is a certain e.g. paymentMethodCode not equal to e.g. ABC or whether that is supposed to check that there isn't any of them.

The test:
test="node != 'ABC' or node != 'XYZ'"

will returns false only when node does not exist.
In all other cases the test will always be true, even if there is only one node - because a node's string value cannot be both "ABC" and "XYZ" at the same time, so at least one of the statements will be true.
You are probably looking for:
test="not(node = 'ABC' or node = 'XYZ')"

which will be true if there is no node with either of these string values.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

If there are multiple nodes, the logic is a bit more subtle, but your argument is still valid: node != 'ABC' is true if at least one node has a value other than ABC, and node != 'XYZ'is true if at least one node has a value other than XYZ, and if there is more than one node then one of these conditions will always be true.

@MichaelKay It will be true if there is at least one node - so obviously it will be true for each and every one of multiple nodes.

I have learned the hard way that with general comparison operators, nothing is obvious.

You haven't explained what you want to check but people struggling with the semantics of XPath general comparison operators might want to check e.g. not(applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode = ('ABC', 'XYZ')) instead of your attempts. That checks is only true if none of the applicationData/remittingAccount/paymentMethodCode is equal to ABC or XYZ.
